# Does every node in a randomized treap has balance factor between (-1 and 1) like an avl? Randomized Treap

Tags: c++11

Can anyone give an argument if every node in a randomized treap has balance factor between (-1 and 1) like an avl?

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not. A randomized treap can have any binary tree shape. Balanced shapes are more likely, but not guaranteed.

Comment: Hi, @TheScorpion_knight! I can see you are a new user to Stack Overflow. Welcome! Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, but does not include code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might help. Best of luck.